# How to find a value in a Row and get the row number in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, row

I'm working on a database on excel using VBA, and I literally don't know this language but I need to do it by next week.

As my question was wrong, I've been analyzing my code and the problem is that I'm trying to get in which Row is a specific value but the code i am using returns nothing. For example, I've got an ID for a client, so what I want to do now is modify or remove the info of that client on the table. I'm trying to do this getting the number of row where that ID is located and changing the cells of that "value" but I can't reach that number.

1. I don't really know how to do that, I've been using this, but it literally returns nothing

   ```
   valor_buscado = Me.Codigo_txt
   ```

   ```
   Set Fila = Sheets("Clientes").Range("A:A").Find(valor_buscado , lookat:=xlWhole)
   ```

   2. If you think there is a best way, I accept suggests as I am completely desperate and don't understand a thing

I've tried some things some good people suggested me before but nothing works, it stills return nothing

Comment: Maybe try `.Find(valor_buscado , lookat:=xlWhole, lookIn:=xlValues)`  I've never seen `Find` fail if the value is in the range being searched.  How have you declared `valor_buscado`?  Would be useful to show the complete code you're trying.

Comment: Is column A formatted as numeric or text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Private Sub Modify_Click()

    Dim FILA As Range
    Dim codigo As Long, valor_buscado, rw As Range
    
    'codigo = CLng(Codigo_txt.value)'???
    valor_buscado = Trim(Me.Codigo_txt) 'in case of leading/trailing spaces
    
    Set FILA = Sheets("Clientes").Range("A:A").Find(valor_buscado, _
                            lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not FILA Is Nothing Then
        With FILA.EntireRow
            .Columns("B").value = Me.txt_name.value
            'etc etc
            .Columns("I").value = Me.txt_email.value
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Value '" & valor_buscado & "' was not found!" '
    End If

End Sub
```